# Galaxy Blaze reboots upon power off

Tags: reboot, power-on, shutdown

I have T-Mobile Galaxy S Blaze, running 2.3.6. I rooted the phone months ago, uninstalled T-Mobile bloatware (using Titanium Backup Free), and have been enjoying using it for a while.

Recently however, I haven't been able to power it off. Everytime I hold the power button and select "Power Off", it goes through the motions but then reboots immediately. I can't think of anything I changed during that time that would cause this, other than software updates. I couldn't tell you which software updates, because I didn't try to turn it off in a long while.

Removing the battery and re-inserting it keeps it off. It's just using the "Power Off" command. Is there anyway I can get a log of what's happening during shutdown? I'm new to Android but not so much to Linux.